Which area of combinatorics is this?

There are $n$ assassins numbered from 1 to n, and all assassins are
initially alive. The assassins play a game in which they take turns in
increasing order of number, with assassin 1 getting the first turn,
then assassin 2, etc., with the order repeating after assassin n has
gone; if an assassin is dead when their turn comes up, then their turn
is skipped and it goes to the next assassin in line. On each
assassin’s turn, they can choose to either kill the assassin who would
otherwise move next or to do nothing. Each assassin will kill on their
turn unless the only option for guaranteeing their own survival is to
do nothing. If there are 2023 assassins at the  start of the game,
after an entire round of turns in which no one kills, how many
assassins must remain? (PUMaC 2023 Combinatorics/A/5)

The solution to this question is available at the given link, and proceeds by induction. This has been classified by Princeton under Combinatorics. I am interested in knowing which area of combinatorics this would fall under. So, for example, if I am looking for further problems of this type, what books/chapters should I be looking for.

Isn't that called "game theory"?

"Combinatorial games" (or "combinatorial game theory").

@CalvinLin Thanks. Any suggestions for resources on these?

@Starlight Greatly depends on what level you're at, and how much work you're willing to put into. Winning Ways for your Mathematical Plays (theory in vol 1, applications are in vol 2), On numbers and games by John conway, Combinatorial Game Theory by Aaron Sigil(this is advanced) would be my initial recommendations
